# What does FCY / F_CY stand for?

Tags: oscillator, microchip

I've come across many equations in microchip datasheets that are based on this value and am looking for a central place to lookup definitions.

F_OSC = oscillator frequency

T_CY = 1 / F_CY = time to execute one assembly instruction?

Comment: Correct enough, though jump operations take multiple clocks on 8-bit PIC devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microchip has a glossary [here](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/designsupport/glossary/home.html). "FOSC" is listed, as well as "TCY" ("The time for an instruction to complete.").

Comment: Minor nit: Tcy is the time of one instruction cycle.  Some instructions take more than one instruction cycle to complete.

Comment: @OlinLathrop is correct, and this is very important to keep in mind. You can't count on an assembly instruction taking just one instruction cycle, some take 2 or more (depending on the instruction set)

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a convention used by a particular microncontroller manufacturer.  Fcy or variants thereof refer to the instruction clock frequency.  "F" means frequency, and "cy" means cycle, or instruction cycle.

Tcy likewise refers to the period of each instruction cycle, with "T" meaning time.  In this case Tcy = 1 / Fcy.

Fosc refers to the raw oscillator frequency driving the micro.  This is often divided by some integer, like 2 or 4 before becoming the instruction clock frequency.

On a old PIC 16 like the 16F877, for example, the maximum clock frequency was 20 MHz, and it took 4 clock cycles to make one instruction cycle.  If you connected a 16F877 to a 20 MHz crystal, Fosc = 20 MHz, Fcy = 5 MHz, and Tcy = 200 ns.

Answer (score 2):

Different manufacturers use different conventions in their datasheets.  It makes it difficult to make a generalized answer, but here it goes!

Frequency (in Hz) and Time (in seconds) are related to each other as you mentioned:

`T=1/F`

In a microcontroller, the basic oscillator frequency is the basis of all the other possible clocks.  This frequency is often given as `F_osc` or `F_clk`.  The duration of each clock cycle is given as `T_osc` or `T_clk`.

Depending on the microcontroller, sometimes an instruction takes multiple clock cycles.  For example, Microchip's PIC18 series (and possibly others, but I haven't used them) use four clock cycles for every instruction cycle.  The instruction cycle time/freq is referred to as `T_inst` and `F_inst`.  In this case, if `F_osc` = 1MHz, then `F_inst` would be 250kHz (a quarter of the speed).  `T_osc` = 1 microsecond, and `T_inst` = 4 us.

`T_inst` and `F_inst` can also be referred to as `T_cy` and `F_cy`.

Then, the rest of the clocks are derived from these.  If you are configuring a timer, for example, the datasheet will state if it is based on `F_osc`, `F_inst`, or some other timebase.

Some uC's perform one instruction per clock cycle, so here is no need to differentiate between the oscillator cycle time and the instruction cycle time.  In this case, `F_cy` would be also used.

Hope this helps!

edit: just to confuse matters, let me add: An instruction cycle is not necessarily the amount of time it takes for an instruction to complete!  Again, using the PIC18 as an example: most instructions take a single instruction cycle, although some can take two.